# How can this binary install be done in NixOS?

Tags: nixos

https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux says

> calibre has a binary install that includes private versions of all its
> dependencies. It runs on 32-bit and 64-bit Intel compatible machines.
> To install or upgrade, simply copy paste the following command into a
> terminal and press Enter:
>
> ```
> sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
> ```

I was wondering what modification needs to be done on the command, when installing the binary on NixOS,

- if I want the minimal modification, OR
- if I want the maximal conformation with NixOS' own ways of package installation, OR
- if I want the maximal scope (e.g. user environment wide, system wide) of running the binary once installed.

(I use "OR" because I am not sure if they could all be accomplished at the same time, and it is helpful if I know those ways for different purposes, just for future reference.)

Thanks.

Comment: IDK NixOS, but you can (and should always) `wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh >linux-installer.sh`, and inspect, understand, modify this local copy **before** granting it full access to your system with `sudo sh ./linux-installer.sh`. Downloading and piping to `sudo sh` is Very Risky. It's like giving a stranger in a hat your house keys while you go to the store. Pobably the stranger will do the right thing. Probably.

Answer (score 2):

On NixOS you'll want to [install the package from nixpkgs](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&show=calibre&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=calibre), either temporarily by running `nix-shell -p calibre` or permanently by adding `pkgs.calibre` to `environment.systemPackages` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`. If you really want a custom installation I'd recommend having a look at the [nixpkgs packaging script](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-23.05/pkgs/applications/misc/calibre/default.nix#L196).